# Parent and child record added on single MVC View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF6 Code First, i have a case in which a student can have one to many addresses. Now i want to use Student model in View to add both the record Student and Addresses of student. But the problem is i cant add addresses of student, is there any appropriate solution for this solution

Here is the example code

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { }

    [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Address()
    { 
    }
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need jquery to dynamically add the html for new `Address` objects. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some examples of how your can approach this

Comment: **How** can't you add addresses? Do you mean in the front-end, the back-end, are they not saved, ...?

Comment: @Gert I want to add addresses in Model from Front-end

Answer (score -2):

Make Listbox for address's and Pass with List that will be really help you and can you paste controller code here?